# EdgeHelper renderized in a wrong position

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm having a trouble with the render of EdgeHelper. When I'm creating the object like that:

```
var outerLineAux = new THREE.EdgesHelper(object, 0x00ffff);
```

The created object reflects the positions of the real object, BUT on there is a huge difference on the axis Y.

For some reason when I'm doing:

```
var outerLineAux = new THREE.EdgesHelper(object.clone(), 0x00ffff);
```

The helper object is created on the right position, but because I'm using a clone object the transformations on the real object they are not reflected on the Helper object, which for me is the correct behavior.

Does anyone has any guesses about it? Even if on my code I'm changing the real object Y the helper shouldn't being follwing this object? Thanks!

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Do you translate the base (parent) object _after_ adding creating `outerLineAux`? Just applying the position of parent object to the edge object (`outerLineAux`) may get you a manual fix in the short-run.

Comment: always provide a testable example.specially in three.js questions.